# How can we import just a few modules from a library while preserving its namespacing?

Tags: javascript, typescript

Let's say we're making a library of utility functions. We want to import some of the utility functions into a front-end project.

To keep things organized, we want the utility functions to always be namespaced. For example, we want to require our developers to call `utils.foo()` and `utils.bar()` instead of just `foo()` and `bar()`.

(The inspiration is the popular library [Rxjs](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/), which exports functions with very generic names like `from` and `find`, which when not namespaced can make code confusing.)

### Simplest but worst solution

The library could have an index file that exports all the helper functions, which can then be imported with `*`, e.g.:

```
import * as utils from `utils/index.ts`;

utils.foo();
utils.bar();
```

However, without some very aggressive tree-shaking this would add all the helper functions into the project's Javascript bundle, which would be a lot of unnecessary bloat if the project only actually uses a few of the functions.

### Mediocre solution

The project could have a file that is an interface between the project and the library, in which we import and export just the functions we want to use in the project:

```
// src/utils.ts

export { foo } from 'utils/foo.ts';
export { bar } from 'utils/bar.ts';
```

```
// src/app.ts

import * as utils from 'src/utils.ts';

utils.foo();
utils.bar();
```

However, this means someone has to maintain that interface, and if the project grows to encompass many modules with separate JS bundles, we could run into the same bloat problem as before.

### Other mediocre solution

We could try to enforce a style rule that the function names have to be prefixed:

```
// src/app.ts

import { foo as utilsFoo } from 'utils/foo.ts';
import { bar as utilsBar } from 'utils/bar.ts';
```

...but that's annoying boilerplate to write, and is hard to enforce.

### What we'd like

We'd like to (a) import just the modules we want, while (b) preserving namespacing.

*Is there a way to dynamically declare properties* on an existing object? We can declare additional global properties by adding them to the `globalThis` object like so:

```
declare global {
    interface HTMLElementEventMap {
        myCustomEvent: CustomEvent;
    }
}
```

...but we're unaware of a way to do this on other objects. To my mind it would look something like this:

```
// util/index.ts

export const utils = {};
```

```
// util/foo.ts

function foo() {};

utils.foo = foo;

declare module utils {
  export const foo = typeof foo;
}
```

```
// util/bar.ts

function bar() {};

utils.bar = bar;

declare module utils {
  export const bar = typeof bar;
}
```

```
// src/app.ts

import { utils } from 'util/index.ts';
import 'util/foo.ts'; // This causes `utils.foo` to be defined

utils.foo();
utils.bar(); // Error: undefined
```

Thanks!

Comment: If you don't like `import { foo as utilsFoo } from 'utils/foo.ts';` (which is usually normal practice), you can name the functions in your library "namespace-wise": `export function utilsFoo( ) {}` => `import { utilsFoo } from 'utils/foo.ts'`